# How to scp from a C program?

Tags: c, scp

The following C program compiles and spits out a a directory listing of "/Users/home/tempdir" directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "/Users/home/tempdir");
        // execl("/usr/bin/scp", "scp", "myfile.txt home@127.0.0.1:/Users/home/scpdir");
    return 0;
}
```

This shows it is possible to execute a binary file from a C program.  I am trying to figure out how to execute the "scp" binary file and input the required passphrase.  How can I modify the above code to achieve a successful file transfer via scp ?

I attempted the line that is commented out above however I get the following message when it is uncommented:

```
usage: scp [-1246BCEpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

So it's obviously trying to perform the scp without the password.  How do I get around this?

Comment: I tried to get rid of the second argument "scp" however I get the same usage statement, except this time I get the warning "main.c:17: warning: not enough variable arguments to fit a sentinel"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could call scp from the command line using expect or something, you are much better off using a library if at all possible.

The general rule when developing is to prefer libraries to system executions whenever possible.  It keeps your code cleaner and more portable.  The exception is if you are writing a shell script.

http://www.libssh2.org/

libssh2 is a free C library that supports password authentication as well as SCP/SFTP and supports OS X.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

libcurl supports pretty much every file transfer type you could want, works on just about every platform you could want, and has bindings for pretty much every language you could want.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, I know, but you'd typically use something like [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) for automating interactive applications in this way.

Comment: So there is no way to do this from C?

Comment: You can use the `Expect` library from C.

Comment: I'm on a macintosh OS X 10.6 - but i only see unix and windows libraries for Expect.  Is there one for mac?

Comment: If it's open source, I can attempt to compile it for mac too

Comment: `Expect` is work product authored by Federal employees, so it's not subject to copyright in the US at least. The source code is available at the [SourceForge repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/expect/code/). I'm not a Mac guy, so can't help you on that one, but I'd be amazed if someone hasn't done it already.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the output you are printing is from incorrect command syntax.  According to the manual page for execl (at least on Arch Linux):

> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(),
>   and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.

So it would seem the correct way to call it is:

```
execl("/usr/bin/scp", "scp", "myfile.txt", "home@127.0.0.1:/Users/home/scpdir");
```

Also, if you want to avoid having to put in the password completely, SSH (which scp is built on top of) can be configured with an "authorized key," which bypasses the password.  It may still ask about unknown key fingerprints, though.
An easy way to set up password-less scp access is to run (from the computer initiating the scp):

```
ssh-copy-id home@127.0.0.1
```

The above command will ask for a password once, they you shouldn't need to enter it again on subsequent ssh operations.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    execl("/usr/bin/scp", "scp", "myfile.txt", "user@IP:path/to/file", (char *)0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything related to password argument in excel function so that we can have uninterrupted communication.

Comment: Instead of using password-based `scp`, you can copy the file utilizing the SSH-public-key. In this scenario, you should use `-i` switch in `scp` command. You can also use other tools such as sshpass which get the raw password in the command.

Answer (score 0):

The following code work for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

execl("/usr/bin/sshpass","sshpass","-p","typeYourPasswd","/usr/bin/scp", "scp", "/home/harekrishna/Downloads/LoRaModule/ArduinoWithMeterCode/dlmsLoraV1.ino", "harekrishna@172.29.118.18:/home/harekrishna",(char *)0);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but this work for me:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    execl("/usr/bin/sshpass","sshpass","-p","typeYourPasswd", "scp", "/home/harekrishna/Downloads/LoRaModule/ArduinoWithMeterCode/dlmsLoraV1.ino", "harekrishna@172.29.118.18:/home/harekrishna",(char *)0);
 
    return 0;
}
```